# postfix not blocking blacklisted IP

Tags: postfix, blacklist

I have a postfix/dovecot server running inside a docker container, and I would like to block some IP addresses from connecting to my SMTP server. I have the following in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, 
    reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining, 
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, 
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, 
    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_checks, 
    permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, 
    reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender, 
    reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch
```

And in `/etc/postfix/client_checks`:

```
# Restrict which clients this system accepts SMTP connection from.

example.com      REJECT No spammers
.example.com     REJECT No spammers, from your subdomain
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd    REJECT Your IP is spammer
```

I also did:

```
$ postmap /etc/postfix/client_checks
```

And reloaded postfix.

But I still get in my logs:

```
Jan 30 10:42:39 mail postfix/smtpd[1443]: connect from unknown[aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd]
Jan 30 10:42:41 mail dovecot: auth: ldap(contact@mydomain.com,::1,<mc2QeU1HQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>): unknown user (SHA1 of given password: 20eabe)
Jan 30 10:42:44 mail postfix/smtpd[1443]: warning: unknown[aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jan 30 10:42:44 mail dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts in 3 secs): user=<contact@mydomain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<mc2QeU1HQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 30 10:42:44 mail postfix/smtpd[1443]: disconnect from unknown[aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd]
```

As you can see, the server still goes through the login process, while I would like it to completely block the IP.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it is typical to permit authentication to all hosts,  on or off blacklists as many blacklists include residential subnet ranges.

however,  if you want to change that you need to change the order of your permit/reject config

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  permit_mynetworks, 
    reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining, 
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, 
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, 
    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
permit_sasl_authenticated
```

this will have undesirable results,  you should take the time to finely tune this config order for your needs